# Best approach/design to web application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been taking a Node.js course on Udemy and would like to apply some of the knowledge I have gained to create a simple web application. I would like to have a user register, which leads him to an admin panel, this part I already have.

This user (requester) can then refer users (invitees) to this website using a unique link. For example he would click a button to generate a unique hyperlink (my idea for this link was to be the http://websiteurl/userid of the requester who is sending the link).

The requester can then send this link through email to their friends to invite them to the website, once they click the link they are taken to a sign up form and when they fill in the form they are linked (added to an array under the original user).

How would I go about setting up this "session", as in make sure that the form that the invitees fill out is linked to the original requester? How can those forms be generated dynamically on the requester's hyperlink?

I'm not looking for the exact code to do this, but rather validation if my idea for the url is a good approach or if there are other approaches I should consider.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code you have written so far?

Comment: Can't you just use a database to associate the referral URL to a particular user account? Then you could log how many times the link is visited, and increment a counter associated to that user.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I can store the URL for the original requester, but how do I generate the sign up form for that particular requester's URL dynamically? Is that something I can do? I can't really wrap my head around this part as I don't know how to generate that form for each requester's unique URL. I have the URL but I don't know how to generate the form/webpage from the click of a button.

Comment: On your user panel (where it would say something like 'click here to generate a link') simply query the database for the user that is currently logged in, and write out their associated 'referral URL' column in the database into the link for them to send out. Then on the registration form use it as a hidden value that is submitted in the POST.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I understand that part, I can display the URL fine. My question is more on how to generate the actual page corresponding to that URL when someone clicks the link.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't create a unique page. I would just have **one** registration page, and simply check for the presence of the referral URL in the GET parameter, like `register.php?referrer=1q2we3r4`. Regular registrations would just be `register.php` (assuming you are running PHP). Then just run a conditional based against the presence of the `referrer` GET, and output "referrer-specific" code in that `if` conditional: `if (referrer) { // build part of form } else { // build rest of form }`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks! I was able to get it working, similar to your suggestion. Thanks for the help! If you want to add that as an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this would require you changing the schema for your database. A user will need to have a property like:

```
{
  referred: []
}
```

The referred array should contain ids or some sort of reference to a user's referred users.

On the "/:userid" route, the form should submit to the route where a new user is created and have a parameter with the user ID. In this case, I am using query parameters.

So if a person were to visit `/foo`, they would get a form that would post to a URL like `/new?userid=foo`.

In that route, you can do something like this (assuming Express):

```
app.post("/new", (req, res) => {
  const userID = req.query.userid;
  const newUser = // create user normally

  if(userID) {
    // `userID` referred this user
    const referrer = getUser(userID);
    referrer.referred.push(newUser);
    save(referrer);
  }
});
```

The `getUser` function should returning the current user, and you should modify the `referred` property with the new user. This code was merely an outline and you should update the user in your database.

In a nutshell, a form should post to `/new?userid=foo`, and when creating a new user, if this parameter is present, you can update the database entry for the user id in the parameter with the id of the new user.